# Как корректно переместить блок через Matrix3d.Displacement?

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

Имеется 2 отрезка. Один - типа **Line**, второй - **динамический блок**, внутри которого Polyline. Создан **Vector3d** из т.1 в т.2.
При попытке переместить оба объекта на один и тот же вектор, происходит разное смещение. Отрезок перемещается как положено на 600 и занимает нужную позицию, а блок почему-то улетает. Что делаю не так? Почему по одному вектору происходит разное смещение?

*line.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(Vec));
blockRef.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(Vec));*

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему создав еще один вектор перемещения позиции блока на созданную линию

---

*Vector3d Vec2 = blockRef.Position.GetVectorTo(line.StartPoint);
br.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(Vec2));*